# Ist der folgende Satz richtig?

Tags: grammaticality

Ist dieser Satz richtig?

> Das ist jetzt die Zeit für dich aufzuhören zu beklagen.

Ich verstehe die Reihenfolge der Verben in Sätzen mit zwei »zu« nicht ganz.

Es tut mir leid danach zu fragen. Ich weiß, ihr mögt solche Fragen nicht ganz, aber dieser Satz bringt mich zum Verzweifeln. Ebenfalls suche ich nach Möglichkeiten, mein Deutsch zu verbessern.

Danke im Voraus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not completely correct:

> Das ist jetzt die Zeit für dich aufzuhören dich zu beklagen.

The positions of both the *zu* was correct already. The remaining problem is that *beklagen* needs *sich*.

The need for the second *zu* comes from *aufhören etw. zu tun*.

Comment: Ist "Jetzt id die Zeit für dich aufzuhören zu beklagen." nicht richtig?

Comment: Ohne das zweite *dich* ist es nicht richtig, denn *beklagen* ist entweder transitiv oder reflexiv und benötigt daher ein Objekt.

Comment: You can also start with "Jetzt ist die Zeit"

Answer (score 1):

Als eleganter empfinde ich eine einfachere Formulierung, wie etwa eine der folgenden:

Du solltest jetzt endlich aufhören, dich zu beklagen.
Es ist an der Zeit, dass du aufhörst, dich zu beklagen.
Das ist jetzt die Zeit für dich, mit deinen Klagen aufzuhören.

Answer (score 1):

Ich sehe 3 Alternativen:

- Das ist jetzt die Zeit für dich, aufzuhören zu beklagen, dass es
  regnet.
- Das ist jetzt die Zeit für dich, aufzuhören zu klagen.
- Das ist jetzt die Zeit für dich, aufzuhören dich zu beklagen.

Man beklagt sich über etwas, oder bei jemandem. Klagen statt beklagen würde auch allein stehen können. Beim bei-jemand-beklagen wird das reflexive *sich*, bzw. hier *dich*, nötig (sich zu beklagen). Ohne eine dieser Ergänzungen oder ohne die Kürzung wirkt es, als fehlte was.

Answer (score 0):

Die Frage der Reihenfolge ist tatsächlich nicht ganz einfach.

Wenn beim Infinitiv mit *zu* ein Objekt steht, steht es vor dem Infinitiv. Das gilt auch für Präpositionalobjekte:

> Es ist Zeit für dich, mit dem Rauchen aufzuhören.

Steht dagegen ein weiterer erweiterter Infinitiv beim Infinitiv mit *zu*, folgt er dem ersten Infinitiv:

> Es ist Zeit für dich, damit aufzuhören, dich zu beklagen.

Daher ist die Wortstellung in dem Beispielsatz richtig, es fehlte nur das *dich*, da *beklagen* hier reflexiv ist. Außerdem wird beim erweiterten Infinitiv üblicherweise ein Komma gesetzt, auch wenn es nach der neuen Rechtschreibung m.W. nicht immer obligatorisch ist. Ein zusätzliches *damit* macht die Sache noch etwas klarer.